# WPF ScrollViewer scrollbar disabled for child grid content

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF grid layout like this:

```
<Grid Margin="7,7,7,7">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                  ... Content ... 
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

When the content in the `ScrollViewer` exceeds the visible height of the `Grid`, the scroll bar still doesn't show. What is going wrong?

Comment: Set VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Visible to see if your scrollview fits into the screen.

Comment: @mami It appears as disabled

Comment: Yes, but do you see both scrolling buttons?

Comment: @mami No, the bottom is missing. Thanks that is the clue to solve this.

Comment: Try setting Grid's rowdefinition to * height instead of Auto (edit: I was slow, you have found it :) )

Comment: @mami I deleted my answer, please add yours so I can thank you SO style :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ScrollViewer grows bigger than the screen so there is no scrolling. Setting Grid's row Height to * from Auto should solve this.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```